# Expose S3 bucket(no public access) via HTTP API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-gateway

If I want to use AWS HTTP Gateway(not the rest api) to expose a public access blocked S3 bucket to return objects (GET requests), how do I go about it? Is it possible to do without a lambda as a broker?

I tried setting the bucket as a static web page host and mapping the gateway request to the bucket url but I got access denied. When I did it, I created a role with the bucket and KMS access, and assigned 'apigateway' as a trusted relationship, hoping the gateway could assume the role when executing the request.

Has anyone managed to integrate the HTTP API gateway and public access blocked S3 bucket successfully?

Comment: Are you looking for: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3

Comment: It says "Create an API Gateway REST API" and I'm looking for "API Gateway HTTP API"